# node js implementation of end function

Tags: node.js, azure

```
var flag= ""
        if(request.method=='PUT')
        {
            request.on('end', function () 
            {  
                        var query = azure.TableQuery
                         if(!error){
                            for (var index in entities) {
                                    if(entities[index].RowKey==xxx)
                                    {                               
                                    flag=555;
                                    }
                                }
                            if (flag==="555")
                            {
                            response.writeHead(200, 
                            send success                                                                                                
                            }
                            else
                            {
                            console.log("the flag is ");
                            console.log(flag);
                            send failure
                            }
            });
        }

    }).listen(9200);
```

This is a Pseudo code.
I want to get the 200 OK send based on the flg.
But I see that always I receive 200 OK with data not present.

I kept some console logs and see that always:"the flag is " is printed first and than the console logs in  if(entities[index].RowKey==xxx) are getting  printed.

I feel from debug logs that azure query is taking time and by that tine node is trying to execute the rest of the code

I also want to know if I am missing something ?

Comment: Try adding a `return;` after `response.end("yes I found it");` and check if it has any effect.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. that did not work. issu is if I keep the block of code (which I mentioned that I removed) it will blindly execute that 200 OK - not present

Comment: From your pseudo-code, the success `.end()` does not break out of response end listener so the interpreter would be executing the after-loop `.end()` printing the invalid input in all instances, even though I'm not sure if it is even possible for it to `.end()` the same response twice. Anyway you should either break out of the function listener or set a `found` flag to ensure that the not found block won't execute when the found one executes.

Comment: the problem I see with the flag is , node is executing the blocks independently . I really dont understand why it is not sequential. I kept console.log I see that flag code is executed before the lookup into the DB so I always get the flag set to default value and the "no present"

Comment: Both the `for` loop and your invalid input `.end()` calls are in the same DB query callback right? That seems weird to happen.

Comment: please check the code I added with flag . always the else will get printed\

Comment: Your code looks just fine. Maybe there's something else behaving differently from the expected, or I am too sleepy to see anything wrong.

Comment: ooh ok...:-)   I have spend lot of time ..not really getting why it is not executing sequentially ..looks it is executing paralley..

Comment: Share your actual code. I can't follow the above "pseudocode." We'd need to see the actual code flow (with the callbacks) to tell you what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have edited the question with more informatiion.

Comment: Please fix your indentation. You also have mismatched parenthesis in there so it is hard to follow.

Comment: I'm unsure if you're intending to put the for loop and if/else code in the callback for the table query - that would be the appropriate way to write this, but unsure if that is what is intended